# How Not To Authenticate Specific User Using Sanctum Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to write web services in Laravel that are protected by `auth:sanctum`, but I want it not to be protected in case of a specific user logged in.

User with these credentials:

- telephone: 0900 000 00 00
- password: 123456

Routes:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/packages', [PackageController::class, 'index']);
    Route::post('/sectors', [IndexController::class, 'sectors']);
});
```

Is there a way to customize the sanctum authentication?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Read this: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#overriding-default-models

Inherit the `PersonalAccessToken` class.
Override the `findToken` method as per your requirements.